# How to configure multiple login pages using multiple databases for authentication in springboot using mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am doing my B.Tech project and everything was going well but now I am stuck in configuring authentication for two different types of users i.e  Customers and Service Providers. I am using MongoDB.

I have two different databases for each user. I am trying to create multiple login pages that would authenticate the user from their respective databases.  I am using order(1) and order(2) for configuration but only order(1) is working.

This is my configuration code.

```
       @Configuration
       @EnableWebSecurity
       public class MultiLoginConfig {

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class DearHelpUserSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

      @Override
        @Bean
        protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new CustomUserDetailsService();
        }

      @Bean
        public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
         return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/hellouser").access("hasRole('USER')")

                .and()
            .formLogin()

                .loginPage("/login1")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
              .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout"). 
            logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        }

}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class DearHelpSPSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

     @Override
        @Bean
        protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new SPUserDetailsService();
        }

        @Bean
        public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
         return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/hellosp").access("hasRole('SP')")

               .and()
            .formLogin()

                .loginPage("/login2")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout"). 
            logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        }


}   

  }
```

I am implementing Custom  UserDetailsService for each user.

Custom implementation for Customers UserDetailsServices is..

```
   public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is(email));
    DearHelpUsers user =
            mongoTemplate.findOne(query, DearHelpUsers.class);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("email %s not found", email));
    }



    return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(),
         AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getRole()));

   }
 }
```

Custom implementation for Service Providers UserDetailsServices is..

```
   public class SPUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("email").is(email));
    ServiceProviders user =
            mongoTemplate.findOne(query, ServiceProviders.class);
    System.out.println(user);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("email %s not found", email));
    }



    return new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(),
         AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getRole()));

   }
}
```

When I am trying to access Customers page i.e "/hellouser", the login page is popping out and authentication is working fine.
But When I am trying to access Service provider page i.e "/hellosp", it is accessible without logging in the user. Authorization for Service providers is not working.
I tried changing the order and observed that authorization for only order(1) code is working but order(2) is not working.
Where am I doing wrong?
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: This is going to be exceedingly complex to manage. It would generally be simpler to write a `UserDetailsService` that distinguishes them internally somehow.

Comment: I don't any idea about what you are suggesting. I would be more clear to me if you write some code samples

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.sbr.platform.services.repository.primary"},
        mongoTemplateRef = "primaryMongoTemplate")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.sbr.platform.services.model")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class PrimaryMongodbConfig {

}
```

Create Secondary db configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.sbr.platform.services.repository.secondary"}, mongoTemplateRef = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SecondaryMongodbConfig {

}
```

```
@Data
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoConfigProperties.class)
@Slf4j
public class MultipleMongoConfig {

    private final MongoConfigProperties mongoConfigProperties;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate primaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoFactory(this.mongoConfigProperties.getPrimary()), this.mongoConfigProperties.getPrimary().getDatabase());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate secondaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoFactory(this.mongoConfigProperties.getSecondary()), this.mongoConfigProperties.getSecondary().getDatabase());
    }

    private MongoClient mongoFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("mongodb://");
        sb.append(mongo.getUsername());
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(mongo.getPassword());
        sb.append("@");
        sb.append(mongo.getHost());
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(mongo.getPort());
        sb.append("/");
        sb.append(mongo.getDatabase());
        sb.append("?authSource=");
        sb.append(mongo.getAuthenticationDatabase());
        log.info("Connection String : {} ",sb.toString());
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongo.getUsername(), mongo.getDatabase(), mongo.getPassword());
        log.info("mongoFactory : {} : credential: {} ", mongo, credential);
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(sb.toString()))
                .build();
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
sbr:
  service:
    mongodb: # MongoDB configuration
      config:
        primary:
          host: localhost
          port: 27017
          database: primary-profiles-collections
          authentication-database: admin
          username: root
          password: example
          repositories:
            enable: true
        secondary:
          host: localhost
          port: 27017
          database: secondary-profiles-collections
          authentication-database: admin
          username: root
          password: example
          repositories:
            enable: true
```

Create 2 repositories and in different package

```
@Repository
public interface ProfilePrimaryRepository extends MongoRepository<Profile, String> {
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileSecondaryRepository extends MongoRepository<Profile, String> {
}
```

Add below code springboot main class

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class ProfileApplicationConfig implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ProfilePrimaryRepository profilePrimaryRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProfileSecondaryRepository profileSecondaryRepository;

    /**
     * Callback used to run the bean.
     *
     * @param args incoming main method arguments
     * @throws Exception on error
     */
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Profile profile = new Profile();
        profile.setProfileType(ProfileType.USER);
        User userProfile = new User();
        userProfile.setPassword("testPWD");
        userProfile.setUserName("test user");
        profile.setBaseProfile(userProfile);
        profile = profilePrimaryRepository.save(profile);
        log.info("Create Profile: {} ", profilePrimaryRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

Result

```
ProfileApplicationConfig  : Create Profile: [Profile(profileType=USER, baseProfile=User(userName=test user, password=testPWD))]
```